# Union of a family of connected pairwise not disjoint subspaces is connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I tried to prove this:

Let $\{A_n | n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ be a countable family of connected subspaces of a topological space $X$ s.t. $A_n \cap A_{n+1} \ne \emptyset$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $\bigcup A_n$ is connected.

I will use this: $\{A_i |i \in I\}$ family of connected subspaces $X$ s.t. $x \in A_i$ for every $i$ then $\bigcup A_i$ is connected.
(It implies also that the union of two not disjoint connected subspaces is connected).

Proof:

Let $B_n := \bigcup_{k=-n}^{n} A_k$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$B_n$ is connected: by induction $B_0=A_0$ is connected and if $B_n$ is connected then $B_{n+1} = B_n \cup A_{-n-1} \cup A_{n+1}$ is connected because it is the union of 3 connected subspaces and $B_n \cap A_{n+1} \supset A_n \cap A_{n+1} \ne \emptyset$, $B_n \cap A_{-n-1} \supset A_{-n} \cap A_{-n-1} \ne \emptyset$.

Since $A_0 \subset B_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have that $\bigcup B_n = \bigcup A_n$ is connected.

Comment: See Also:[Union of path-connected pairwise not disjoint subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833993)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct except for a slight (notational?) inaccuracy: you want to show that $B_{n+1}=B_n\cup A_{-n-1}\cup A_{n+1}$ is connected. If I understand you correctly, you claim this is the case since all three sets are connected and $B_n\cap A_{-n-1}\neq\emptyset\neq B_n\cap A_{n+1}$, so you can apply the general result to the family $\{B_n, A_{-n-1}, A_{n+1}\}$. The result you quoted, however, requires that $\bigcap A_i\neq\emptyset$. This can be fixed by a successive argument: the lemma, applied to $\{B_n, A_{-n-1}\}$, yields that $C:=B_n\cup A_{-n-1}$ is connected. Now, $C\cap A_{n+1}\supseteq B_n\cap A_{n+1}\neq\emptyset$, so you can apply the lemma again, this time to the family $\{C, A_{n+1}\}$, to obtain the connectedness of $C\cup A_{n+1}=B_n\cup A_{-n-1}\cup A_{n+1}$.

Btw, I really like the idea behind your proof! I would have gone back to the proof of the lemma fron which you can, with a little fiddling, obtain the result as well - but yours is much more elegant.

Comment: Yes when i proved the connection of the union of the 3 sets I mentally did what you wrote but I did not write it! Thank you!!!